# Why is the limit as $x$ approaches $0$ of $\frac{\sin(5x)}{x} = 5$?.

Tags: limits

Why is $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(5x)}{x} = 5$? Is there some trig identity according to which $\sin(cx) = c\cdot\sin(x)$ (or any identity that could help solve this problem)? I already know that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$, but I'm not sure exactly how to proceed in this particular case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make the substitution $x\mapsto \frac y5$.

Answer (score 4):

It is well known limit that $\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { \sin { x }  }{ x } =1 } $ so $$\\ \lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { \sin { 5x }  }{ x } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ 5\cdot \frac { \sin { 5x }  }{ 5x }  }  } =5$$

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the expression by 5/5, then you have $$\frac{sin5x}{5x}\cdot5$$ which is basically $5\cdot1$

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to use [L'Hopital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule).

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(5x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\frac{d}{dx}(\sin(5x))}{\frac{d}{dx}(x)}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{5\cos(5x)}{1}=5$$

Comment: It is already assumed that $\lim\frac{\sin x}x=1$, so it is probably OK, but note that you need to know that limit in order to deduce that the derivative of $\sin$ is $\cos$. I would therefore be careful when using l'Hopital anywhere near that limit.